# Chatter Email Sender Account Wrong for Only 1 User after Community Deployment to Production

Tags: email, chatter, partner-communities, community

we deployed a Partner Community the production org and now a single user is getting all their Chatter email notifications from the Partner Community email sender account instead of the standard Chatter email sender.  This is happening just for that one user; all the other users in the org are getting their Chatter emails sent correctly. The affected user is in the System Administrator profile and does happen to be the account the org was set up under. Other users in the same profile are not experiencing the same behavior.

All settings have been checked and verified – can’t find anything that appears to be causing this.

Has anyone run into this or heard of it before? What would cause the Chatter email sender to be different for one user over another?

Any insights would be appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I asked an engineer who works on the email feature, and he said...

"Because posts on records can be visible both in a partner community and in standard Chatter, it's often appropriate for a notification email to be branded for either standard Chatter or the partner community. When an email notification to an internal user is being created for a post on a record, if the email pref is turned on in Chatter, the notification is sent using the Chatter email sender. If the email preference for the user is turned off in Chatter but turned on in the partner community, the notification is sent using the sender from the partner community. A workaround would be to make the email preferences for the user in Chatter match the user email preferences in the community."

Answer (score 0):

The email sender will depend on the community that the user is getting the email from. You can configure the sender email per community. Is it possible that the newly created community has only the sys admin user as its community member and that's why this user is seeing community emails while the others are seeing the regular chatter user as sender?